# Concat child items in to column by id

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. the first is the item table with columns:

```
itemId|itemNumber|description
1      abc        xxxx
2      def        xxxx
3      hij        xxxx
```

Then I have a subitem table with columns:

```
parentItemId|childItemId
1            2
2            3 
1            3
3            2
3            1
```

Im trying to select a list of itemNumbers with the list of child itemNumbers concatenated in the 3rd column like so:
results:

```
ItemNumber|description|childItemNumber1, childItemNumber2, childItemNumber3...
abc        xxxx        def,hij
def        xxxx        hij
hij        xxxx        def,abc
```

So i need to look up the item numbers for the parent child relationship in the first table before concatenating them.

ive tried something like this:

```
SELECT c.itemNumber, c.description,  GROUPBY_CONCAT(SELECT a.itemNumber from Item as a inner join SubItem as b on a.itemId = b.childItemId where a.Itemid = b.parentItemId) FROM Item as c WHERE 1
```

but i dont even think its close

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  A SQL Fiddle can also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires two joins and an aggregation:

```
select p.itemNumber, p.description,
       GROUP_CONCAT(ci.description) as children
from Item p left join
     SubItem s
     on p.itemId = s.parentItemId left join
     Item ci
     ON s.childItemId = ci.ItemId
group by p.ItemId;
```

Subqueries are not necessary.

Comment: there is no s.itemnumber only s.parentid and s.childid, that is the challenging part.

Comment: @user1336827 . . . The sample data greatly clarifies your problem.  I've modified the answer.

Comment: this is close I think, if you finish the second ON and change ci.description to ci.item number. But the children are all just the same item number as the original itemnumber

Comment: @user1336827 . . . There should be no `where`.

Comment: perfect! that looks like exactly what i want. thanks for the help!